# Online-hosted JWT Encoder with option to call via API

Tags: python, node.js, jwt, webhooks

I am trying to create a DocuSign integration from my app, primarily to be triggered via Zapier or Make.com. However, I need to go through the route of creating a developer account and sending it as an ISV licensed DocuSign partner due to a number of reasons (which don't really matter for this part of my problem).

Essentially, I need to created an encoded JSON Web Token by using the RS256 algorithm. I have all my ducks in a row, including all the info needed for the encoding (header, body, and signature), but I need to find a way to encode those items in the RS256 format in order to request an access token from DocuSign.

Unfortunately, I can't use a tool like https://jwt.io/ because that's a manual process and my integration will be making a bunch of calls from different accounts and we can't wait for someone to try and process these 24/7.

Here's what I tried so far:

1. Host a Python script on Python Anywhere. PROBLEM: As far as I can tell, you can't call the script via webhook (POST request).
2. Host a Python script on APIFY. PROBLEM: APIFY can't install the PyJWT library because it can only install external libraries with Node.js (I don't know enough about that to make that happen).
3. Use Zapier or Make directly. PROBLEM: If I'm trying to run Python code on Zapier, the same issue with the library is happening where Zapier doesn't allow for external libraries and there are no other encoding functions.

Basically, I would need to find something that can be called via a POST request or something that functions directly in Make.com to encode the following sample data.

```
Header

{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

Body

{
  "iss": "<your_integration_key>",
  "sub": "<your_user_ID>",
  "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
  "iat": <current_unix_epoch_time>,
  "exp": <current_unix_epoch_time+6000>,
  "scope": "signature impersonation"
}

Signature

RSASHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(body),
  "<your_public_RSA_key>",
  "<your_private_RSA_key>"  
)
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated because I spent all day trying to figure this out with no solution yet.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, there's a lot of unnecessary information.. You have an app, and you want to encode a JWT somewhere, with a POST request? Sounds like you need an API server running, which is also what you ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out after working on it for a few more hours. Here's what I did:

Host a Python code (Flask server) that takes care of the encoding on Heroku and then make a POST request to the individual URLs in the Flask server.

```
import jwt

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/create_jwt', methods=['POST'])
def create_jwt():
    data = request.get_json()
    payload = data.get('payload')
    private_key = data.get('private_key')
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(payload, private_key, algorithm='RS256')
    return jsonify({"jwt": encoded_jwt})

@app.route('/verify_jwt', methods=['POST'])
def verify_jwt():
    data = request.get_json()
    encoded_jwt = data.get('encoded_jwt')
    public_key = data.get('public_key')
    decoded_payload = jwt.decode(encoded_jwt, public_key, algorithms='RS256')
    return jsonify(decoded_payload)
```

You can follow the instructions on Heroku on how to create a git and how to get it onto Heroku. It was very straightforward. Just make sure that you choose Python as the buildpack in the app's settings and create a requirements.txt file in the root directory that includes the following:

```
PyJWT~=2.7.0
Flask~=2.3.2
gunicorn
cryptography
```

And also a Procfile (with no file extension) that has the following (if your main Python file is called main.py and you kept your Flask Object as "app". Otherwise rename those two parts):

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

Once it's live, you should by able to make a raw POST request with the payload being a json of the body and the private key as a string. Just make sure that if there are line breaks in the private key to mark them as \n instead of an actual line break.